# Consul (KV) is wiping off all data when restarting Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, consul, consul-kv

I am currently working on Spring micro-service(Eureka Implementation) project. To manage the distributed configuration we are using Consul KV. We are deploying services on Kubernetes cluster.

The issue I am facing that, whenever I restart the cluster for Consul it deletes all the data of KV. I am creating Kubernetes cluster on local with docker image by having Deployment.yaml file.
Please refer the below Deployment.yaml file for consul.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: consul
  labels:
    app: consul
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 8500
      name: consul
  selector:
    app: consul
    
---
    
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: consul
spec:
  serviceName: consul
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: consul
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: consul
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: consul
        image: hashicorp/consul:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8500
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: consul-lb
  labels:
    app: consul
spec:
  selector:
    app: consul
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8500
```

After some research I found that we can specify the -data-dir location in config, so I have modified StatefulSet kind yaml as below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: consul
spec:
  serviceName: consul
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: consul
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: consul
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: consul
        image: hashicorp/consul:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8500
        args:
            - "agent"
            - "-server"
            - "-data-dir=/home/consul/data"
```

But after this Consul UI is not getting started, so wanted some help to resolve so it stores the data even after I delete Consul cluster.
PS: I tried deploying cluster with helm, and it was persisting the data but I did not know how to make that cluster StatefulSet so I can refer it in other services with static url.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please note that k8s `pods` are by default ephemeral even if you deploy them as `StatefulSet`.

`StatefulSet` is providing you option for `pod` with define name eg. `consul-0` rather that standard `consul-<<random string>>`. It also keeps track of where to deploy `pod` in case you have different zones and you need to deploy `pod` in the same zone as `storage`.

What is missing in your manifest is `volumeMounts` and `volumeClaimTemplates` sections . If you set your data directory to `/home/consul/data` your manifest should looks similar to this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: consul
spec:
  serviceName: consul
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: consul
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: consul
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: consul
        image: hashicorp/consul:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8500
        args:
          - "agent"
          - "-server"
          - "-data-dir=/home/consul/data"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: consul-data
          mountPath: /home/consul/data
  volumeClaimTemplates:                       # volume claim template will create volume for you so you don't need to define PVC
  - metadata:
      name: consul-data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "my-storage-class"    # you can get this with kubectl get sc
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

Regarding you second problem with `consul` UI I would not help much since I never use `consul` but I can advise to deploy `helm chart` once again and check how arguments are passed there.

Comment: Hi Michal, Thanks for responding here. I tried with your suggestion but unfortunately it did not work. After some research and learning I tried to deploy the consul with Helm Chart and it satisfied my requirements, I was able to connect to consul service created by Helm with <service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:port Thanks.